# PHP POST from iOS app

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I need to access POST for PHP from my iOS application. I can't seem to get it to work though.

Here is a very short snippet of the PHP:

```
$post_data = $_POST["function"];

if ($function == 'post_data') {
    //do stuff, not important
else if($function == 'send_stuffz') {
    //do stuff, not important
}
```

How do I access this portion of the code?

I thought it could just be through a URL such as:

```
fakewebsitename.com/file.php?function=post_data
fakewebsitename.com/file.php?function=send_stuffz
```

But that doesn't work.

In the iOS app, I have this thus far:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]]; <-baseURL = fakewebsitename.com/file.php in this "instance"
[urlReq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Not sure how to proceed...

Comment: `$function ` is not definied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this function is incorrect**

```
$post_data = $_POST["function"];

if ($function == 'post_data') {
    //do stuff, not important
else if($function == 'send_stuffz') {
    //do stuff, not important
}
```

you are not defining variable `$function` please change as follow

**please change to**

```
$post_data = $_POST["function"];

if ($post_data == 'post_data') {
    //do stuff, not important
else if($post_data == 'send_stuffz') {
    //do stuff, not important
}
```